# Identifying distinct rows across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, distinct

Let's say I have two tables with identical structure, call them A & B.  The only columns of concern for this issue are product_type, price, and volume.

Each combination of product_type & price may be repeated multiple times in each table with varying volumes.  I'm trying to find instances of a combination having a different TOTAL volume in one table than the other.

This would include when a combination from table A is not represented in Table B whatsoever, or vice-versa.

===================

Example:

Table A:

```
ID   Product_type   Price  Volume
---  ------------   -----  ------
1         X           $1     10
2         X           $1     11
3         Z           $2     10
```

Table B:

```
ID   Product_type   Price  Volume
--   -------------  -----  -------
1         X           $1     21
2         Y           $1     5
3         Z           $2     7
4         Z           $2     4
```

Notice that sum of volumes of X @ $1 in Table A is 21, which matches Table B.
Y @ $1 is present in Table B, but not in A.
Z @ $2 is present in both tables but the sums of their volumes differ.  I would like the query to return each product_type and price combination that breaks the rules (i.e. Y @ $1 and Z @ $2).

I've tried using GROUP, UNION, DISTINCT, sub-queries and various combinations of the above but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table a (ID integer, Product_type char(1), Price float, Volume integer);
create table b (ID integer, Product_type char(1), Price float, Volume integer);

insert into a (ID, Product_type, Price, Volume) values
(1, 'X', 1, 10),
(2, 'X', 1, 11),
(3, 'Z', 2, 10)
;
insert into b (ID, Product_type, Price, Volume) values
(1, 'X', 1, 21),
(2, 'Y', 1, 5),
(3, 'Z', 2, 7),
(4, 'Z', 2, 4)
;

select 
    a.Product_type as Product_type_a,
    a.Price as Price_a,
    a.Volume as Volume_a,
    b.Product_type as Product_type_b,
    b.Price as Price_b,
    b.Volume as Volume_b
from (
        select Product_type, Price, sum(Volume) as Volume
        from a
        group by Product_type, Price
    ) a
    full outer join (
        select Product_type, Price, sum(Volume) as Volume
        from b
        group by Product_type, Price
    ) b on a.Product_type = b.Product_type and a.Price = b.Price
where 
    a.Volume != b.Volume
    or a.Volume is null or b.Volume is null
;
 product_type_a | price_a | volume_a | product_type_b | price_b | volume_b 
----------------+---------+----------+----------------+---------+----------
 Z              |       2 |       10 | Z              |       2 |       11
                |         |          | Y              |       1 |        5
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works great, just had to modify it to union two joins as MySQL doesn't support full outer joins.

Comment: @user1681248 Didn't know that. I tested it in postgresql as that is what I have access to now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is what you were looking for. I apologize for the weird where/not in syntax, with the subquery in concat this seemed to be most readable approach.

```
(
SELECT
  "TableA",
  TA.*

FROM TableA AS TA

WHERE CONCAT(product_type, price,
             (SELECT SUM(volume) FROM TableA WHERE product_type = TA.product_type AND price = TA.price))

NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(product_type, price, SUM(volume)) FROM TableB GROUP BY product_type, price)
)

UNION

(
SELECT
  "TableB",
  TB.*

FROM TableB AS TB

WHERE CONCAT(product_type, price,
             (SELECT SUM(volume) FROM TableB WHERE product_type = TB.product_type AND price = TB.price))

NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(product_type, price, SUM(volume)) FROM TableA GROUP BY product_type, price)
)

#ORDER BY <column>
```

Output:

```
TableA  ID  Product_type  Price  Volume
TableA  3   Z             $2     10
TableB  2   Y             $1     5
TableB  3   Z             $2     7
TableB  4   Z             $2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to [work for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/401ed/3):

```
SELECT a.Product_type, a.volume, b.Product_type, b.volume
FROM
  (SELECT Product_type, SUM(volume) AS volume
  FROM tbl1 GROUP BY Product_type) a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Product_type, SUM(volume) AS volume
  FROM tbl2 GROUP BY Product_type) b ON b.Product_type = a.Product_type
WHERE a.volume <> b.volume
```

**Result**

```
| PRODUCT_TYPE | VOLUME | PRODUCT_TYPE | VOLUME |
-------------------------------------------------
|            Z |     10 |            Z |     11 |
```